# Win7 - Unable to create new folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, user-folders

Recently completed a fresh install of Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit on a laptop and have just noticed that no matter which folder I navigate to on the system, I am unable to right click and create a new folder..

The entire "New" option is missing after right clicking!

Attempted a registry change within HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New\

Changing the default value to: {D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}

No luck...

Answer (score 0):

Update - Issue resolved.

Downloading a fix from http://help.wfu.edu/public/computers/windows/new-folder-missing-in-desktop-context-menu/NewFolderFix.reg?attredirects=0&d=1 seemed to do the trick.

Once downloaded, I ran the .reg file which made a change to the registry, in which after a reboot the missing function came back to life.